# exit code 141 in Hadoop streaming

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

Come across exit code 141 in Hadoop streaming jobs.

After search in Google, I found the 141 error is about pipe broke...

My job is to generate protobuf instance from json.

When I look carefully at the error log, I found the warn exits:

`org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit`

Does anyone know what it means?

Comment: Hadoop does not have great support for Protobuf... What exact commands are you running?

Comment: I used a customized java class that could read pb input from mapper output and outputformat the pb streaming.

Comment: Does that class work even if you `cat file.pb | java Mapper.class | sort | java Reducer.class`? Because that's effectively what hadoop streaming does.... More specifically, binary file types aren't meant to be used for streaming, only line delimited formats (why do you need to use Hadoop?)